# How to create an Iterface for a Class that is in a DLL C#

Tags: c#

Lib:

```
class SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Updated");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        apple.FruitLib.Update();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I started like this:

```
class Apple 
{
    public SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver FruitLib { get; set; } = new SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver();
}
```

And then I did this:

```
interface IFruit
{
    SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver FruitLib { get; set; }
}
class Apple : IFruit
{
    public SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver FruitLib { get; set; } = new SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver();
}
```

Hoping for :

```
class Apple : IFruit
{
    public IFruitLib  FruitLib { get; set; } = new SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver(); //To support both the library I dont have control over and the new one
}
```

Instead of using just SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver in the Apple class I would like to create my own Library that does exactly the same functionality(its done in a different way) how can I modifiy apple to support both libraries even though SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver  does not comes with an iterface that I can use to create my own.

Comment: Start with using the correct term, interface. Look into design patterns like facade or decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I modifiy apple to support both libraries even though SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver does not comes with an iterface that I can use to create my own.

You can use "encapsulation".  Just wrap it in a class you have full control over. eg

```
class Pear : IFruitLib
{
    private SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver foo;
    public Pear(SomeLibraryIHaveNoControlOver foo)
    {
       this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void SomeFruitLibMethod()
    {
        foo.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well but I came across this issue with collections  https://stackoverflow.com/q/71384760/5326036